# json returning list<customers>

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm returning `List<Customer>` as json result in my controller. in the client script i can see the customers fine being returned.

can i somehow use the forin loop? because when i try it says that var i is undefined.

```
for (var i in customers)
{
alert(i.CustomerName);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
for (var i in customers)
{
    alert(customers[i].CustomerName);
}
```