# display my json list of customers in asp.net mvc with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a customer list object back from server and i want to display in my view. What's the best way to do this? for instance, showing the customers in a div on the page

Comment: two questions for one problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827498/json-returning-listcustomers a bad practice i would say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your business and how you want to display it. There is no generic solution for this.
In case you want to display the json "as is" (don't know why you'd like to to this, maybe for debugging), you could put it inside a pre:

```
<div>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
</div>
...
$("#pre").html(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

JSON.stringify will work on modern browsers.
But, (I insist), there is no "correct" answer for your question, it depends specifically on your "business" needs.